Button to maximize, minimize and restore window are not working
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
VMware Workstation 17 Pro (17.5.1)
Oracle Java 22.0.1
Apache Netbeans 21
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS as a VMware 17 guest, with Windows 10 as the host.
When the window is maximized, the maximize, minimize and close buttons in Chromium and Netbeans do not work.
Those buttons work when the window is not maximized. However, I cannot resize the window by dragging on edges.
Other applications such as Firefox and Text Editor work as expected, maximized or otherwise.
Does anyone have a solution?
Thank you.
